# RDSのユーザ定義関数が登録できない件について

Tags: aws, postgresql

RDS-postgresqlで、以下のようなユーザ定義関数を登録したいのですが、superuser権限がないため、エラーになってしまいます。

```sql
db=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public".bittoint4(bit) RETURNS int4 AS 'bittoint4' LANGUAGE 'internal';
ERROR:  permission denied for language internal
```

rdsadminのロールを付与しないと、上記は正常終了できなさそうなのですが、RDSではrdsadminのロール付与もできなさそうです。

```
rds-db=> grant rdsadmin to postgres;
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
```

すみませんが、回避策ご存じの方おりましたらご教授頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

plpgsqlで同様の内容に書き換えて、定義することで対応できました。

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION square_root(precision bit) RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN precision;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```